# How to not pull in duplicate rows when joining tables in Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, vertica

Is it possible to not pull in duplicate rows when creating a table from multiple table joins in Vertica SQL? I am wanting to filter out entire duplicate rows - so rows where all column values in that row are the same as another row.

I tried doing this using Group By after searching online, but I still find a large amount of duplicate rows. FYI I am checking for duplicates by downloading my data, opening with excel, and removing duplicates. My end goal is to not have to download the data because we are using a system where we do not have a method for re-loading the data onto the server system we are using (#ThanksCerner).

I was reading a few methods where you create a temporary table and delete duplicates, but also read that it is not recommended to use DELETE for tables with a large # of records, so I was trying to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Update: This is the query I am using. I will work on creating some test data I can share for it

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.condition_code, c.condition_primary_display, 
     c.effective_date_id AS condition_effective_date,
     bc.member_id, bc.plan_name, bc.payer_name,
     e.facility, e.service_delivery_location, e.hospital_service_display, 
     e.encounter_type_display, e.encounter_type_primary_display, 
     e.discharge_disposition_display, e.admission_source_display, 
     e.status_display, e.actual_arrival_dt_tm, e.discharge_dt_tm,
     p.full_name AS patient_name, p.postal_cd, p.county_display, 
     p.state_primary_display,
     pd.birth_date, pd.ethnicity_primary_display, pd.gender_primary_display,
     pr.race_display,
     po.name AS provider_name, po.provider_id,
     epr.relationship_type_primary_display
    FROM PH_D_Person p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_D_Person_Demographics pd
    ON p.empi_id = pd.empi_id AND  p.population_id = pd.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_D_Person_Race pr
    ON pd.empi_id = pr.empi_id AND pd.population_id = pr.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_F_Condition c
    ON pr.empi_id = c.empi_id AND pr.population_id = c.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_F_Encounter e
    ON c.encounter_id = e.encounter_id AND c.empi_id = e.empi_id AND 
    c.population_id = e.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_F_Encounter_Benefit_Coverage bc
    ON e.encounter_id = bc.encounter_id AND e.empi_id = bc.empi_id AND 
    e.population_id = bc.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_F_Encounter_Personnel_Reltn epr
    ON bc.encounter_id = epr.encounter_id AND bc.empi_id = epr.empi_id AND 
    bc.population_id = epr.population_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PH_D_Provider po
    ON epr.provider_id = po.provider_id
    WHERE c.condition_code IN ('J44.0', 'J44.1', 'J44.9', 'J47.1', 'J47.0', 
    'J47.9', 'J43.2', 'J43.9', 'J41.8', 'J41.1', 'J43.8', 'J43.1', 'J41.0', 
    'J43.0', 'J42')
    AND year(e.actual_arrival_dt_tm) ='2017'
    AND year(e.discharge_dt_tm) ='2017'
    ORDER BY bc.member_id DESC;
```

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @jarlh SELECT DISTINCT doesn't seem to apply to multiple fields. I tried using that as well and it still gave me many duplicate values.

Comment: Well, I don't know Vertica, but in SQL `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to the whole selected rows.

Comment: @jarlh that's what I thought as well which is why I was using it, and then I randomly decided to double check by downloading my data and found there were still duplicates. I may just be SOL on my own and need to reach out to the company that runs this system. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unless you include your table definitions, some sample data, your current query, and the desired result, it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @mustaccio I will work on creating an example similar to mine - I can share our query but I need to create some made-up sample data since we work with PHI

Comment: Unless there's a bug in Vertica that nobody has encountered until now, this query will return only unique records. I rather think your method of checking for duplicates is at fault.

Comment: @mustaccio my method for checking for duplicates is downloading my data to a csv file, opening it with excel, and then removing duplicates based on all columns for the table. Is that not accurate?

Comment: Apparently it is not. Data are converted twice, once into CSV, then into whatever Excel thinks it should look like, so what you see in Excel may be nowhere near what you have in the  result set.

Comment: @mustaccio I am going to ask if you can explain more on this? I have spent the last few hours researching why my data would get duplicated when downloading the data as a .csv and then when opening the .csv with excel. I cannot find anything and cannot understand why this would happen. It seems very counter-intuitive to me, but I likely just don't understand enough of how SQL works then and would like to better understand.

Comment: It's not about SQL -- it's about data representation in various layers. Suppose you have a character column `col1` that contains three values: `''` (empty string), `' '` (single space), and `null`. For the SQL engine these are three different values, so `select distinct col1 from...` will return three rows. However, when you export this to a CSV file, unless you take precautions, you'll get two lines with nothing in them except the new line character, plus one line with a single space before the new line. When you now import this into Excel you'll get three identical empty cells.

Comment: The above is just one example of how distinct SQL values might result in "duplicates" when twice converted into Excel via CSV. You may want identify the exact rows that Excel thinks are duplicate and review their contents at every preceding step: as returned by the SQL query and after having been written as CSV.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you very much for that explanation! That makes sense. I tested with a smaller subset of data, and found that distinct does work. I also double checked and apparently we do have at least one column that is 3-4 different values strung together, so that is likely the source of this problem in the other table I originally posted about. Can I assume that the results table within Vertica does not split the character column up into the separate values?

Comment: Typically a DBMS engine (including Vertica) does not do anything it has not been explicitly instructed to do, so I would not expect it to split one column value into multipe values on its own.